# HTTPS on same port as HTTP?

Tags: node.js

I'm writing an HTTP/HTTPS proxy server in Node.JS, I want the server to handle HTTPS traffic on the same port as HTTP.

The below image explains why I want to do this, the user can just check the box...

[image: Proxy Settings]

I realize that I can't have 2 servers listening on the same port, but is there a way to setup a *main* server that forwards the traffic to either HTTP or HTTPS traffic?

Something like this:

```
http.createServer(myHTTPCallback).listen(3129, '127.0.0.1');
https.createServer(myHTTPSCallback).listen(3130, '127.0.0.1');


//Then a main server that will listen for both kinds of traffic

main.createServer(function(req, res){
    if(/*Traffic is HTTPS*/){
        //Forward to 127.0.0.1:3130
    }
    else{
        //Forward to 127.0.0.1:3129
    }
}).listen(3128, '192.168.0.2');
```

**How would I code the above?**

---

**EDIT** - *As per @Chris Jester-Young answer*

I created this simple server, but I only receive output for HTTP requests. Also breakpoints or console logs don't trace:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(req, res){
    res.write('<h1>Resquest Received</h1>');
    res.write('<span>Requested URL = ' + req.url + '</span>');

    res.end();
}).listen(3128);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to listen to both HTTP and HTTPS on the same port, in your specific case of writing a proxy server. Browsers connect to proxy servers via HTTP, whether for proxying HTTP or HTTPS requests. HTTPS requests use the `CONNECT` HTTP method to open a direct connection to the HTTPS server---that `CONNECT` request is still done in the unencrypted portion of the proxy traffic.

---

Edit: Here's what I think your code should look like:

```
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    // Handle normal requests here
}).on('connect', function (request, socket, head) {
    // Handle CONNECT requests here
}).listen(3128);
```

Comment: I have an HTTP server that is working as a proxy. To test your idea I placed a breakpoint in the callback, but it's not triggered when visiting an HTTPS URL.

Comment: Where's your breakpoint set at? At the connection handler? Remember that HTTPS connections use the `CONNECT` method so you have to watch for that (and not for `GET`, `POST`, etc.).

Comment: Please see my edit. I place the breakpoint or `console.log` right at the top of the callback, but it's not triggered.

Comment: I think you're listening for the wrong event. Read this: http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_connect

Comment: Thanks for the help. I didn't realize it needed another listener for the CONNECT method.

Comment: I didn't either, seeing as I've never used node.js before, but I cloned the node.js source and started digging. :-D